# Apache - Blocking direct access to image

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration

I use apache 2.4.41 and I would like to deny direct access to image files on my server. I've implemented the following code in my apache configuration file :

```
SetEnvIf Referer "(www\.)?mywebsite\.net" localreferer
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif)$">
    Require env localreferer
</FilesMatch>
```

However I have a strange behavior. In a web browser, when a try to access an image file directly with its url, I don't get a 403 error code (as expected) and the image is displayed. But, when reloading the page (F5 or cmd+R on a mac), the ressource is blocked and a 403 error status is displayed.

When trying a `curl -I`, I have the following result :

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2022 14:31:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://www.mywebsite.net/error/403.php
```

But I should get `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`...

Could someone help me with this issue ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think htaccess can do this well enough `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png|bmp)$ - [F]`

Comment: OK, but this does not answer my question. I prefer using the `FilesMatch`since I already have rewrite rules defined